# How to use a Typescript type alias of a function type on a function declaration

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, type-alias

I have this type alias with a function type.

`type ADD_FUNCTION = (x: number, y: number) => number;`

I can do this:

```
type ADD_FUNCTION = (x: number, y: number) => number;

const add: ADD_FUNCTION = (x, y) => {
  return x + y;
};

const result = add(1,2);
console.log(result);
```

It works because I'm storing the function into a variable named `add` which I'm giving the type `ADD_FUNCTION`.

But what if I don't want to store that function inside a variable and declare it with a regular named function.

```
function add(x,y) {
  return x + y;
}
```

Is there a syntax which allows me to define that function type using the `type` alias `ADD_FUNCTION` ?

The following code does not work:

```
function add: ADD_FUNCTION (x,y) {
  return x + y;
}
```

**NOTE:** I know that the following code is possible, but I really would like to use the `type alias`.

```
function add(x: number, y: number): number {
  return x + y;
}
```

Comment: If you want a non-arrow function, `const add: ADD_FUNCTION = function (...) { ... }`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The only option to use the alias is keeping the function reference into a variable?

Comment: You can do it the other way, derive the type from the function, but otherwise no. As you've seen, there's no syntax that allows it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe , Thanks. That answers my question. Was wondering if this was either impossible or just something unusual.